# Using chrome devtools persistence along with minified/preprocessed javascript & CSS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying out [Chrome Devtools persistence/Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow). It works great for a very simple project with no build tools. I can edit the CSS in the inspector and the changes show up live, I can edit HTML and JS in the sources panel once I right click add a workspace, then add a mapping to the remote files.

It's very lightly documented and doesn't seem well used though, I'm wondering if it's possible to use this feature and have code that's been run through a preprocessor and have my updates apply to the source file. Obviously I'd have to set up source maps, but it doesn't seem from what I've found so far that you can do that along with the persistence feature.